# will-change: opacity, transform; causes smoothed text in CSS

Tags: html, css, font-smoothing, will-change

so I was messing about with MaterializeCSS and was realizing that when putting a button with the class `"waves-effect"` caused all text to smooth out and become a little blurry sort of say. So through a process of elimination, I found out that `will-change: opacity, transform;` caused this is happen.

This is the difference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA32c.jpg

Anyone know how or what causes this effect to happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share with us a fiddle, so we can help you.

Comment: Sure, dont really much of a difference here hence  why I never realised it in the past, however I mostly see it as in the Imgur, with the Coolvetica Light Font. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yvnsrkvv/ Also, it's not really something I need to fix, I really just want to know what causes this to happen with some fonts, and what goes on behind "will-change". Cheers.